# removing duplicate characters from string

Tags: c++, string

I want to remove the duplicate characters from a string. The logic I was using is to take a string and then copy it into another and then point the first character of the first string and loop it through the all characters of other string and if same remove but I am going wrong somewhere can you guide us.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char a[100],b[100];
    cout<<"Enter the string:";
    cin>>a;

    strcpy(b,a);
    int len1=strlen(a);
    int len2=strlen(b);


    for(int i=0;i<len1-1;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<len2-1;j++)
        {
            if(a[i]==b[j])
            {
                b[j]=b[j+1];
            }
            len2--;
        }
    }


    cout<<"Without char dupli is:"<<b;
}
```

Comment: have a look at [`std::unique`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/unique/). Additionally - if you are using C++ use `std::string` instead of `char` arrays.

Comment: Another thing to note is string a and b are the same, no need to have two calls to strlen(). Since you are using C++ you can also just use .size()

Comment: @Fureeish `std::unique` only works on sorted sequences.

Comment: @cdhowie I am aware of that. If I was sure that the sorting was not the issue I would've proposed it as an asnwer

Answer (score 2):

This is better done by using the standard library:

- [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) to hold the string instead of character arrays.
- [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) to hold the set of characters already encountered.
- [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) with a lambda function to reorganize the string so the duplicates are at the end.
- `std::string::erase` to remove the duplicates.

Here is an example of this approach:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string str;

    if (!(std::cin >> str)) { return 1; }

    std::set<char> chars;

    str.erase(
        std::remove_if(
            str.begin(),
            str.end(),
            [&chars] (char i) {
                // If encountered character, remove this one.
                if (chars.count(i)) { return true; }

                // Otherwise, mark this character encountered and don't remove.
                chars.insert(i);
                return false;
            }
        ),
        str.end()
    );

    std::cout << str << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

([Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae43f0e2eb5a670c))

Answer (score 0):

In your code when you 'remove' a character, all you're doing is copying the character after it and ignoring everything else. This causes numerous bugs in your code. When you remove you should copy all characters after the duplicated character.

Currently when you remove a character

```
    character| -> hharacte|r
    ^             ^<
```

What you should do

```
    character| -> haracter|r
    ^             ^<<<<<<<<
```

Also I think you need a null character at the end of b for cout to print it correctly?

(| = end of the string via len2, ->  remove operation, <  copied to previous spot, ^ character to replace)

Comment: I was thinking to just move the elements when the duplicate elements are found. Just as we do in array delete operation. Can we do in that way? Can you all suggest any changes in my program as I have implemented it on my own.

Answer (score 0):

I have used an extra **O(N)** space([string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)) and the time complexity of the solution is **O(N)**.

```
# include <iostream>
# include<string>
# include<cstring>        // For memset function
using namespace std;


int main() {
    string s,p;        // s-> original String, p-> extra string(without duplicates)
    cin>>s;
    bool alphabets[26];  // Assuming your string contains charactes between a-z only.
    memset(alphabets,false,26);
    for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++)
    {
        if(alphabets[s.at(i)-'a']==false)    // If that character was marked false i.e if it was not present in original 
        {
            alphabets[s.at(i)-'a']=true;    // mark that character true
            p.push_back(s.at(i));           // Insert that character in string p
        }
    }
    cout<<"Original String: "<<s<<endl; 
    cout<<"String without duplicates: "<<p;
    return 0;
}

Input: 
abcdabasfa

Output: 
Original String: abcdabasfa
String without duplicates: abcdsf
```

Here's the Code [Link](https://ideone.com/fiilz5).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way to remove the duplicates, It depends on marking duplicate with '*' but this will not work if string contains symbols too.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char a[100],b[100];
    cout<<"Enter the string:";
    cin>>a;
    strcpy(b,a);
    int len=strlen(a);
    int pointer = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
       if(a[i] == '*')
         continue;

       for(int j=i+1;j<len;j++)
       {
         if(a[i]==b[j])
         {
            a[j]='*';
         }
       }
      b[pointer] = a[i];
      pointer++;
    }
    b[pointer] = '\0';

    cout<<"Without char dupli is:"<<b;
}
```

this code is **O(N*N)** which take a lot of time with long strings, so this is another way to optimize it:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<set>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    set<char> containerOfUniqueCharacter;
    char a[100],b[100];
    cout<<"Enter the string:";
    cin>>a;
    strcpy(b,a);
    int len=strlen(a);
    int pointer = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        //put size of set in a variable 
        //insert char into the set
        //check size of set after inserting
        //if it has changed then it is a new char else it is not
        int testBeforeInsert = containerOfUniqueCharacter.size();
        containerOfUniqueCharacter.insert(a[i]);

        if(containerOfUniqueCharacter.size()!=testBeforeInsert){
         b[pointer] = a[i];
         pointer++;
        }
   }

   //give end to the character array
   b[pointer] = '\0';

   cout<<"Without char dupli is:"<<b;
}
```

This code is **O(N)** as inserting in a **set** data-structure is **O(1)**.

the above code with using **Strings**:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<set>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    //this code works with strings containing all kind of symbols
    set<char> containerOfUniqueCharacter;
    string a,b="";
    cout<<"Enter the string:";
    cin>>a;
    for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++)
    {
        int testBeforeInsert = containerOfUniqueCharacter.size();
        containerOfUniqueCharacter.insert(a[i]);

        if(containerOfUniqueCharacter.size()!=testBeforeInsert){
          b += a[i];
        }
   }
   cout<<"Without char dupli is:"<<b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**C-ish solution**

I'll put this since your code looks more like C than C++ (`strlen` and `cout` on the same page looks a little fishy). This solution will consist of an additional array of 127 booleans (127 characters in ASCII) that will keep track of the characters you encountered. Initially the array will be set to false, since we didn't find any character yet. This solution will save us the overhead required to actually look for the characters into another array or set using a search algorithm. Keep in mind that `strlen` computes the string's size every time it is called, so if you know you have 2 same size strings don't call `strlen` for both. The character in the input array will be used as indexes in the bool array. This will work since characters are integers. So `foundChar[c]` will pretty much translate to "Was c found?"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>


int main()
{   
    const int N = 255;
    const int ASCII_CHARS = 127;
    char a[N]; //input string
    bool foundChar[ASCII_CHARS]{ false }; 
    char b[N]; //output string

    std::cin >> a;

    int len = strlen(a);
    int lenb = 0; //b's length(initially 0)

    for (int i = 0; i <= len; i++)
    {
        char c = a[i];
        if (!foundChar[c]) //first char encounter
        {
            b[lenb] = c; 
            lenb++; //we increment it every time we add a character
            foundChar[c] = true; //we found the char
        }
    }

    std::cout << b;

    return 0;
}
```

You might have noticed that, in my for loop, I wrote `i <= len`, which should take me outside of the string. While this is true, it won't take me out of the string's memory. A c++ string is always null-terminated. That means that every string ends with an '\0' or 0. This control character tells us where the string ends(pretty much that's how `strlen` computes the size of it). So that means that when we allocate the string's memory we should always keep in mind that extra byte required to store the control character(`char[3] c = "abc"` will give you an error.The correct way of doing it is `char[4] c = "abc"`, "abc" being equivalent to "abc\0"). That being said, `strlen` gives you the "useful" length of the string, without the 0 at the end. So, the for loop iterates through all the string's characters, but it also makes sure to copy the '\0' at the end of b, since it is a character itself and `foundChar[0]` will be false until the end.

**About performance**

It is an O(N) solution. I only used 127 extra bytes of space (which is insignificant). I don't think you can get more performance out of it, since iterating through the string at least once is necessary. Anyway, I think it is the cleanest way for what you want to achieve.

Comment: I was thinking to just move the elements when the duplicate elements are found. Just as we do in array delete operation. Can we do in that way? Can you all suggest any changes in my program as I have implemented it on my own.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code it is easy to understand and implement.**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
        string str,temp;
        cin >> str;      
        int n = str.size();               //size of string str store in n
        for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
        {
            temp += str[0];            //append(add) first character of str to string temp
            str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(),str.end(),str[0]),str.end());    //remove same character from string str eg. str[0] = 'a' ; then this line of code remove all 'a' character from string str.
        }
        str = temp;          
        cout << str << endl;          //print string with unique characters
}
```

Here we add the first character of string str to the string temp and remove that character from the original string, we will repeat this and at the end, str becomes an empty string because we remove all characters from it on the other hand we add unique character in string temp during iteration.